# How to find average without using group by statement in sql

Tags: sql

I want to know if its possible to get the functionality of group by with using it.
I need to find average without using group by.
basically I am looking for an alternative for the below simple query without using `group by`.

```
SELECT 
  AVG(salary)
  , g.emp_id 
FROM #emp e ,#salary d 
WHERE e.emp_id=d.emp_id 
GROUP BY e.emp_id
```

Comment: Why do you want to avoid `group by`?

Comment: Tushar, don't use implicit SQL '89 syntax, it's an anti-pattern, use explicit join syntax instead: `SELECT AVG(d.salary), e.emp_id FROM #emp e INNER JOIN #salary s ON (e.emp_id = s.emp_id) GROUP BY e.emp_id`

Comment: That looks like you're trying to get an average per employee.  Or do you just want one figure - the average across all employees?

Comment: This is what group by is designed for, and any other method would be less efficient, so I second Jim's question.  Perhaps you have requirements for the format of the result set that you aren't sharing?

Comment: Yes, I need average for each employee based on employee id. I am looking for alternative without concern of efficiency.

Comment: can anyone help converting this into sql '92 syntax??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option

```
SELECT  e.emp_id ,
    ( SELECT    AVG(salary)
      FROM      #salary d
      WHERE     d.emp_id = e.emp_id )
FROM    #emp e
```

Comment: Would you know how to right this in SQL '92's Explicit join syntax.

Comment: @Tushar, this uses a subquery instead of a join, so there is no join to rewrite.

Answer (score 3):

If your DB supports `partition` you can do:

```
SELECT e.emp_id
       , AVG(s.salary) OVER(PARTITION BY s.emp_id) AS average_salary
FROM #emp e
INNER JOIN #salary s ON (e.emp_id = s.emp_id)
```

I fail to see the purpose of this exercise however.
It just makes your query harder to read, harder to debug and replaces commonly used syntax with obscure code.

**Group by rocks**
Did you know that `group by` even as a 'grant total' function build in

```
SELECT 
  AVG(d.salary)
  , e.emp_id 
FROM #emp e 
INNER JOIN #salary s ON (e.emp_id = s.emp_id) 
GROUP BY e.emp_id WITH ROLLUP
```

See: SQL-server: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522495.aspx
MySQL: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html

**Remark**
Do not use implicit SQL '89 syntax, as much as I love Bill Joel's `we didn't start the fire` it is time to move on to the much better SQL '92's Explicit join syntax.
*As for songs, 1989 really has a better [year](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Hot_100_number-one_singles_of_1992_%28U.S.%29):*

Comment: Thanks Johan, i will try to learn 92's syntax. Can you tell me how will i write the answer given by David in 92's syntax?

Answer (score 0):

If you really wanted to do this, you could SELECT ... ORDER BY employee and then write a cursor to calculate the averages piecemeal.  I don't see any good reason to do this, though.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
SELECT AVG(d.salary) over (partition by null),
       e.emp_id 
FROM #emp e
  JOIN #salary d ON e.emp_id = d.emp_id;
```

It will return all employee ids and the average salary calculated for all employees (so it will contain the same information for all rows).

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

`select * from (SELECT 
  AVG(salary)
  , g.emp_id 
FROM #emp e ,#salary d 
WHERE e.emp_id=d.emp_id 
GROUP BY e.emp_id`) a`